# Search in Dynamic Array

Tags: c++, arrays, list, dynamic

When I'm searching an integer in my dynamic array, the search function isn't working well as its always showing its positioned at 1. whether the data is actually there or not.

What i'm actually trying to do is using dynamic data structure, I'm adding the data. Deleting, searching and saving to txt file. and Loading it back. But the problem is search. I used switch cases and search is at Case 4.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream> //to save file in text

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *p1;
    int size = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    p1 = new int[size];


    int userchoice;
    int i;
    int position;


    while (1)
    {
        cout << "Please enter your choice " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "To insert Press '1'" << endl;
        cout << "To Delete press '2'" << endl;
        cout << "To View press '3'" << endl;
        cout << "To Search press '4'" << endl;
        cout << "To Save Press '5'" << endl;
        cout << "To Load Previously saved Data press '6'" << endl;
        cout << "To Exit press '7'" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> userchoice;


        switch (userchoice)  // User's selection from the menu
        {
        case 1: //Insert Number
            cout << "Enter a Number:  ";
            cin >> p1[size];
            counter++;
            size++; //Add's memory space
            break;

        case 2: //Delete Number

            int udelete;

            cout << "Enter a number to delete:  ";
            cin >> udelete; //User enters Number to be deleted

                            //Checking if the number is in an array.
            for (position = 0; position<size; position++)
            {
                if (p1[position] == udelete)
                    break;
            }
            if (position>size)
            {
                cout << "The number is not in the memory:  ";
                cout << endl;
                break;
            }
            for (i = position; i<size; i++) {
                p1[i] = p1[i + 1];
            }
            size--;
            cout << "Successfully Deleted!!! ";
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 3: // View


            for (i = 0; i<size; i++)
            {
                cout << "Your data" << " " << i << " " << "-->" << p1[i] << endl;
            }
            break;

        case 4:
        {
            int usearch;

            cout << "Please enter the figure you would like to search ";
            cout << "->";
            cin >> usearch;

            for (i = 0; i>size; i++)
            {
                if (p1[size] == usearch)
                    break;
            }
            if (usearch == size)
            {
                cout << "not found. ";
            }
            cout << "Position at: " << i + 1 << endl;
            break;

        }



        case 5: // Save

        {
            ofstream save;
            save.open("Dynamicdata.txt", ofstream::out | ofstream::app);

            for (i = 0; i<size; i++)
            {
                save << p1[i] << endl;
            }

            save.close();
            cout << "File Saved " << endl;

            break;
        }

        case 6: //Read from File
        {


            string read;

            ifstream file_("Dynamicdata.txt");

            if (file_.is_open())
            {
                while (getline(file_, read))
                {
                    cout << read << "\n";
                }
                file_.close();
            }
            else
                cout << "File Not open" << endl;
            cin.get();
            break;

        }

        case 7:
        {
            return 0;
        }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the size of your array is 0.  Here you set `size` to 0 and then `size` for the size of `p1`

```
int size=0;
int counter=0;
p1 = new int[size];
```

You are going to need to make size bigger so that you can actually store elements in `p1` or instead of using arrays and dynamic memory allocation use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and let it handle that for you.

Answer (score 1):

The code has undefined behaviour because initailly the dynamically allocated array pointed to by pointer `p1` has no elements

```
int size=0;
^^^^^^^^^^
//...
p1 = new int[size]; // size is equal to 0
```

So in the following code snippet an atttempt to write data to `p1[size]` results in undefined behaviour

```
case 1: //Insert Number
        cout<<"Enter a Number:  ";
        cin>>p1[size]; // undefined behaviour
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        counter++;
        size++; //Add's memory space
        break;
```

You need to reallocate the array to reserve memory for the added new element.

Take into account that for example this loop

```
        for (i = 0; i>size; i++)
                    ^^^^^^^
        {
            if (p1[size] == usearch)
                break;
        }
```

will never iterate because variable `i` set to zero can not be greater than `size` that at least equal to zero.

And it would be logically more correct to write

```
            if (p1[i] == usearch)
                ^^^^^
```

instead of

```
            if (p1[size] == usearch)
                ^^^^^^^^
```

Consequently this if statement

```
        if (usearch == size)
            ^^^^^^^
        {
            cout << "not found. ";
        }
```

should be replaced with this for statement

```
        if (i == size)
            ^^
        {
            cout << "not found. ";
        }
```